# How to trigger execution of arbitrary JavaScript code in browser from Bokeh Server?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

How to trigger execution of arbitrary JavaScript code in browser from Bokeh Server? 
Is the simplest way to create hidden button and then 'trigger' it?

Answer (score 2):

From Bryan Van de Ven @bryevdv Mar 08 20:52

> @Sklavit you will probably want to wait for [bokeh/bokeh#5941](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5941)

From description:

> The API will be very similar to the existing `on_change` and `js_on_change` API used to register callbacks triggered by property changes.

As for my question on 2017-03-09, there are several way to trigger JS code from server:

- Define JS callback as

  ```py
  some_model.callback = CustomJS(code="alert('hi!')")
  ```

  **What is triggering `callback` is unclear**
- Define JS callback as

  ```
  some_model.js_on_change = CustomJS(code="alert('hi!')")
  ```

  **`js_on_change` is present only for few `model`s**
- Code injection in `DataTable`'s

  ```
  TableColumn(..., formatter=HTMLTemplateFormatter(template="<% alert('hi!') %>"))
  ```

**My current solution**
Create hidden holder

```
    callback_holder = PreText(text='', css_classes=['hidden'])
    callback = CustomJS(args={}, code='alert(cb_obj.text);')
    callback_holder.js_on_change('text', callback)
```

And then in other part of application:

```
    def update():
        callback_holder.text = 'data for JS code'
    curdoc().add_next_tick_callback(update)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `templates`. An example of how to use templates for bokeh-server app can be found here:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/crossfilter

Comment: `templates` are static declaration of page content. Question is about dynamic trigger from server to page.